# date object within struct.......SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, struct

I'm creating an iOS app using Swift; it creates and manages user tasks. I have each task within the struct object, but I can't figure out how to initialize the date object.

```
struct DailyTask: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var taskDescription: String
    var dueDate: **HERE?**
    var lengthInDays: Int
    var theme: Theme
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, taskDescription: String, dueDate: String, lengthInDays: Int, theme: Theme) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.taskDescription = taskDescription
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.lengthInDays = lengthInDays
        self.theme = theme
    }
}

extension DailyTask {

    struct Data {
        var title: String = ""
        var taskDescription: String = ""
        var dueDate: **HERE??**
        var lengthInDays: Int = 5
        var theme: Theme = .seafoam
    }

    extension DailyTask {
    static let sampleData: [DailyTask] =
    [
        DailyTask(title: "Homework #15 - Reading", taskDescription: "Read first three chapters of textbook. Read first three chapters of", dueDate: **WHAT CLEAR** , lengthInDays: 2, theme: .magenta),

    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Date()`? Or if you want it a certain time in the future, `Date().addingTimeInterval(amountOfTime)`

Comment: The way that it works is that the struct would could contain a date from the user picked in a datepicker but im not sure how to comunicate back and forth between the two

Comment: You haven't shown any code with a `DatePicker`, so it's not really possible to give a recommendation about how that would work. Can you show where you create the `DailyTask` and how it connects to the view with the `DatePicker`?

Comment: `dueDate` should be of type `Date` and getting and setting the date from the DatePicker is easy

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have due date as `Date`

```
struct DailyTask: Identifiable, Codable {
let id: UUID
var title: String
var taskDescription: String
var dueDate: Date?
var lengthInDays: Int
var theme: Theme

init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, taskDescription: String, dueDate: Date?, lengthInDays: Int, theme: Theme) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.taskDescription = taskDescription
    self.dueDate = dueDate
    self.lengthInDays = lengthInDays
    self.theme = theme
}
```